# Model Binding a WebSocket Message in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, websocket

I've implemented a class which inherits from IHttpHandler and essentially calls the following upon a request.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(ProcessSocket);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpException("This isn't a WebSocket request!");
    }
}
```

`ProcessSocket` is an async operation which accepts the HttpContext of the request as a parameter. This method then goes on to parse the request asynchronously, process the data, and eventually send the response back to the client.

Would it be possible to utilize the model binder commonly used in MVC controller action parameters to process the websocket message and construct a model?

I'm currently accessing the request data as follows:

```
ArraySegment<byte> _Buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
WebSocketReceiveResult _Result =
                    await _Socket.ReceiveAsync(_Buffer, CancellationToken.None);
```